# Clarification about LE encryption field used in the LL_FEATURE_REQ and LL_FEATURE_RSP

Tags: android, encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I sniffed with my Ubertooth One, some BLE packets between my Android phone and my BLE device, and I would like clarifications about a particular field and its meaning.

After the connection is established, a `LL_FEATURE_REQ` is sent with the value of the `LE Encryption` field set to `0` (`false`).

According to the offical documentation (BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2 [Vol 6, Part B], 4.6 FEATURE SUPPORT):

> "When this information is sent from a Controller to a Host, a bit set to 0 indicates
>   that the Link Layer Feature is not supported in this Controller; a bit set to 1
>   indicates that the Link Layer Feature is supported in this Controller.
>
> When this information is sent from a Controller to a peer Controller, a bit set to 0
>   indicates that the Link Layer Feature shall not be used by the Controllers; a bit
>   set to 1 indicates that the Link Layer Feature may be used by the Controllers.
>   "

Also in the `LL_FEATURE_RSP` the `LL Encryption` field is set to `0` (`false`).

So, according to this Message Sequence Chart (BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2 [Vol 6, Part D]), before sending the `LL_FEATURE_REQ`, the Master device (my Android phone), first reads the supported features and then sends the request. 
[image]

Does this mean that my Android device does not support communication encryption?

**EDIT**:

Below is the Wireshark output (on the left is the the Bluetooth HCI snoop log from my Android phone, and on the right the packtet captured with my Ubertooth):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LL_FEATURE_REQ contains a 0 for position of LE Encryption (position 0), then that device's controller does not support encryption. The LL_FEATURE_RSP contains the bitwise AND of the master's and the slave's supported features.

But it sounds strange that an Android device wouldn't support encryption...

Comment: Hi! Yes, I've done different test, and also I've update my question. So it seems from the  Bluetooth HCI snoop log (on the left) that LE Encryption is supported (is set to 1), but instead from the packets captured (on the right), it seems different (the LE Encryption field is set to 0). In your opinion, why this happen? Am I missing something?

Comment: What Wireshark plugin are you using? It decodes the packet in the wrong way, namely reversed.

Comment: I'm using Wireshark Version 2.2.5. As far as I know, in the latest version of Wireshark there is no need for plugin : "Wireshark version 1.12 and newer includes the Ubertooth BLE plugin by default." I followed this guide to capture BLE in Wireshark with standard Wireshark builds. Should I install a particular pluging instead

Comment: I guess someone will need to send a patch to Wireshark that fixes the issue.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some bluetooth low energy .pcap files? My device has limited capabilites, so I think that all the security features are not implemented (so don't appear in my captured files). I really want to understand how security manager protocol works in practise.

Comment: The smp pairing request and response messages should contain all information about capabilities.

Comment: Yes I know. But these messages are missing in my .pcap files. Are these two packets always trasmitted?

Comment: I'm a bit confused..the pairing request and response messages are used to exchange different information, like the I/O capabilities. Then, based on these information, one of paring method is selected. How can be possible that these messages are sent when the pairing is done? (if you want we can continue talking in a stackoverflow chat)

Comment: If the devices are not bonded, then at the moment you call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond(), it will send out the pairing request message.

Comment: Great. So if the creatBond() function is not implement in the Android app, all the pairing messages will never be sent. Am I right? (many thanks)

Comment: Yes. But of course another app can also createBond.

Answer (score 0):

After the last Wireshark update (Version 2.4.0 using on Windows), this problem seems to be fixed.
Now the LL Encryption field is correctly set to 1 (true). Here is the same packet:
[image]